# Compositional data constraints in optimization

Tags: optimization, constraints

**Problem**

As part of an optimization problem I have a matrix $\Gamma$ that is the response in a multivariate regression problem

$$\Gamma = \mathbf{AB}$$

where $\mathbf{A}$ is a matrix with $m \times r$ coefficients for the $m$ polynomials of order $r-1$ and $\mathbf{B}$ is the design matrix with $r \times n$ entries.
This is part of the maximum likelihood estimation of $\mathbf{A}$ in order to fit a basis expansion model where $\Gamma$ contains the coefficients for the $m$ basis functions for $n$ moments in time.
 However, **there are constraints to this problem**, which are

- The column sum of $\Gamma$ should be equal to 1
- Every value in $\Gamma$ has to lie within the interval $[0,1]$

In order to incorporate these constraints there are several options:

1. Apply the **isometric log-ratio transformation** (see [this document on compsoitional data analysis](http://www.sediment.uni-goettingen.de/staff/tolosana/extra/CoDaNutshell.pdf)) to the regression problem, which implicitly handles both constraints
2. Approach this as a constrained optimization problem and use appropriate solvers
3. Make this into an unconstrained problem using the [penalty method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penalty_method), basically introducing somewhat rigorous penalty terms to the optimization problem that punish violation of the constraints.

Currently I have used approach 1 and modeled $\Gamma$ using the ilr transformation 
$$\Gamma = ilr^{-1}(\mathbf{AB})$$

because it seems to be the more elegant soultion to incorporate the constraints. However, since the coefficients in $\mathbf{A}$ are now part of the ilr transformed space I find it hard applying regularization to them in order to improve the fit of the model. I guess for this it would be easier to have $\mathbf{A}$ in the original space, therefore I am considering options 2 and 3.

**Questions**

1. Which option would you recommend in this case?
2. I understand that the penalty method can only serve as an approximation to the actual constrained problem, but is it still worth considering? I have tried coming up with fitting penalty functions for this case but since they should also be differentiable I am struggling with it.

---

**Edit:**

In the constrained case it is not straight forward to me whether I can in fact pass these constraints to the solver, it'd be appreciated to get some input on this.

Now what is a bit annoying is that Matlab reshapes $\mathbf{A}$ to a column vector before passing it to the solver.

$$\mathbf{A} = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  \alpha_{1,1} & \alpha_{1,2} & \cdots & \alpha_{1,r} \\
  \alpha_{2,1} & \alpha_{2,2} & \cdots & \alpha_{2,r} \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  \alpha_{m,1} & \alpha_{m,2} & \cdots & \alpha_{m,r} 
 \end{pmatrix};  
\mathbf{a} = \begin{pmatrix}
  \alpha_{1,1}\\
  \alpha_{2,1}\\
  \vdots\\
  \alpha_{m,1}\\
  \alpha_{1,2}\\
  \vdots\\ 
  \alpha_{m,2}\\
  \vdots\\ 
  \alpha_{m,r}\\
 \end{pmatrix}  \\
$$

and only allowing one linear inequality and one linear equality constraint:

1. $\mathbf{C}\cdot \mathbf{a} \leq \mathbf{d}$
2. $\mathbf{D}\cdot \mathbf{a} = \mathbf{e}$

I think I can't even make my constraints fit that, can I?

Comment: Just use a high quality constrained solver. Let it handle the constraints, not you. Those are linear constraints, which are easy for good solvers to handle.

Comment: The problem with constrained solvers (at least in Matlab) in this case is that the constraints don't apply to A directly but rather to AB.

Comment: Isn't $B$ an input matrix of numerical values? So $AB$ is linear in $A$, so your constraints on $AB$ are linear constraints on $A$. You should be able to input those constraints in the MATLAB optimization toolbox, or other tools.

Comment: I've tried that today and failed to make them fit - I've updated my question with info regarding that

Comment: Yes, you have to do some finagling, but it can be done. The easy way is to use a modeling front-end, which allows you to specify variables and constraints in matrix form, and does the conversion under the hood to/from solver standard form. For instance, YALMIP (free) under MATLAB. Or CVX for a more limited class of problems than YALMIP allows. if your objective is linear least squares, then CVX will work, and has a smaller learning curve than YALMIP. Your constraints are linear, and so are a piece of cake to handle with YALMIP or CVX.