# Formulate indirect constraints on reshaped matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, matlab, constraints

*Note:* This question is related to [an earlier question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2744722/compositional-data-constraints-in-optimization) that I decided to vote to be closed and narrow down my problem in this question so it might maybe help people facing a similar problem.

I'm trying to solve the constrained optimization problem

$$\min_{\mathbf{A}}\quad l(\mathbf{A}) $$
with 
$$l(\mathbf{A}) = -\Phi\cdot (\mathbf{AB})$$ being the log-likelihood of the model I'm trying to fit ( originally a maximization problem but since MATLAB only does minimization I changed it).

$\mathbf{A}$ is a matrix with $m \times r$ coefficients of $m$ polynomials of order $r-1$ and $\mathbf{B}$ is the design matrix with $r \times n$ entries.
$$\mathbf{AB} =
 \begin{bmatrix}
  a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & \cdots & a_{1,r} \\
  a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & \cdots & a_{2,r} \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  a_{m,1} & a_{m,2} & \cdots & a_{m,r} 
 \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
  b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} & \cdots & b_{1,n} \\
  b_{2,1} & b_{2,2} & \cdots & b_{2,n} \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  b_{r,1} & b_{r,2} & \cdots & b_{r,n} 
 \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix}
  \gamma_{1,1} & \gamma_{1,2} & \cdots & \gamma_{1,n} \\
  \gamma_{2,1} & \gamma_{2,2} & \cdots & \gamma_{2,n} \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  \gamma_{m,1} & \gamma_{m,2} & \cdots & \gamma_{m,n} 
 \end{bmatrix}=\Gamma 
$$
 subject to the constraints

1. $\sum_{j=1}^{m} \gamma_{j,i} = 1 \quad\forall i\in\{1,\cdots,n\}$
2. $0 \leq \gamma < 1 \quad \forall \gamma\in \Gamma$

**However, I'm struggling to formulate these constraints in a form that MATLABs [fmincon](https://de.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) function accepts**. This is hard for me because 1) the constraints don't directly apply to $\mathbf{A}$ and 2) althought the function accepts a matrix as input (in my case $\mathbf{A}$) it will be passed to the linear constraints as a column vector $\mathbf{a}$ of form

$$\mathbf{a} = \begin{pmatrix}
  a_{1,1}\\
  a_{2,1}\\
  \vdots\\
  a_{m,1}\\
  a_{1,2}\\
  \vdots\\ 
  a_{m,2}\\
  \vdots\\ 
  a_{m,r}\\
 \end{pmatrix}  \\
$$

As can be taken from the link, the function accepts linear constraints in the form (I adjusted the notation to be consistent with this post)

1. $\mathbf{C} \mathbf{a} \leq \mathbf{d}$
2. $\mathbf{D} \mathbf{a} = \mathbf{e}$
3. $\mathbf{L} \leq \mathbf{a} \leq \mathbf{U}$

**But I've since failed formulating my constraints in a form that fits the function and would like to ask your help with this. Is this even possible?**

Another option would be to include them as non-linear constraints, which are defined as functions and get $\mathbf{A}$ instead of $\mathbf{a}$ passed to them.

Comment: Other than basic bookkeeping with indices and using that $\gamma_{i,j}=\sum_k A_{i,k}B_{k,j}$, I do not see a problem.